# Python Selenium get_attribute not returning value

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract the data-message-id from the following html. My original goal is to extract the data-message- id for the span containing a particular text and then clicking on the star_button to star it.

```
    <div class="message_content_header">
        <div class="message_content_header_left">
                    <a href="/team/krishnag0902" target="/team/krishnag0902" class="message_sender color_U5TPDSMQQ color_9f69e7 member member_preview_link " data-member-id="U5TPDSMQQ">krishnag0902</a>


                    <span class="ts_tip_float message_current_status ts_tip ts_tip_top ts_tip_multiline ts_tip_delay_150 color_U5TPDSMQQ color_9f69e7 hidden ts_tip_hidden">

                        <span class="ts_tip_tip ts_tip_inner_current_status">
                            <span class="ts_tip_multiline_inner">

                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
            <a href="/archives/C5UGEFBS9/p1498084447119862" target="new_1498118826460" class="timestamp ts_tip ts_tip_top ts_tip_float ts_tip_hidden ts_tip_multiline ts_tip_delay_300"><i class="copy_only">[</i>4:34 PM<i class="copy_only">]</i><span class="ts_tip_tip"><span class="ts_tip_multiline_inner">Yesterday&nbsp;at&nbsp;4:34:07&nbsp;PM</span></span></a>





                <span class="message_star_holder">
```

Star this message

```
        </div>


    </div>


        <span class="message_body">hoho<span class="constrain_triple_clicks"></span></span>









                    <div class="rxn_panel rxns_key_message-1498084447_119862-C5UGEFBS9"></div>






    <i class="copy_only"><br></i>


    <span id="msg_1498084447_119862_label" class="message_aria_label hidden">
        <strong>krishnag0902</strong>.
        hoho.

        four thirty-four PM.
    </span>
```

and i am using the code on the above span(message_star_holder) which is returning a None

```
data_mess= star_button_span.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class= 
'star ts_icon ts_icon_star_o ts_icon_inherit ts_tip_top star_message 
ts_tip ts_tip_float ts_tip_hidden btn_unstyle']")
print data_mess.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print star_button_span.get_attribute("data-msg-id")
```

Answer (score 0):

`star_button_span` doesn't have `data-msg-id` attribute. `data_mess` has

```
print data_mess.get_attribute("data-msg-id")
```

Comment: @KrishnaGaurav The only difference I can see from the previous question is that the new html is not connected to it. Is this a question about something  else?

Comment: Yes this is a separate, since i started dealing with a different html block which might have the information i am looking for. is there a way to get in touch with you directly? Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: @KrishnaGaurav If you have a new question you should post a new question, not edit an old one.

Comment: You are correct, but i thought this would draw your attention better, i will post a new one.